# efficient iteration & application of a function in pandas, polars or torch? Is lazy possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pytorch, python-polars

**Goal**:
Find an efficient/fastest way to iterate over a table by column and run a function on each column, in python or with a python library.

**Background**:
I have been exploring methods to improve the speed of my functions. This is because I have two models/algorithms that I want to run one small, one large (uses torch) and the large is slow. I have been using the small one for testing. The small model is seasonal decomposition of each column.

**Setup**:

```
Testing environment: ec2, t2 large. X86_64
Python version: 3.11.5 
Polars: 0.19.13 
pandas: 2.1.1 
numpy: 1.26.0
```

demo data in pandas/polars:

```
rows = 11020
columns = 1578
data = np.random.rand(rows, columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# df_p = pl.from_pandas(df) # convert if needed.
```

**Pandas**

pandas and dict:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
import pandas as pd

class pdDictTrendExtractor:
        
    def __init__(self, period: int = 365) -> None:
        self._period = period
        self._model = 'Additive'
        
    def process_col(self, column_data: pd.Series = None) -> torch.Tensor:
        self.data = column_data 
        result = seasonal_decompose(self.data, model=self._model, period=self._period)
        trend = result.trend.fillna(0).values
        return trend

    @classmethod
    def process_df(cls,  dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        trend_data_dict = {}
        for column in dataframe.columns:
                trend_data_dict[column] = cls().process_col(dataframe[column])
        trend_dataframes = pd.DataFrame(trend_data_dict, index=dataframe.index)
        return trend_dataframes

import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
trend_tensor = pdDictTrendExtractor.process_df(df)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
execution_time = stop - start

print("Program Executed in "+str(execution_time))
```

Program Executed in 14.349091062998923

with list comprehension instead of for loop:

```
class pdDict2TrendExtractor:
        
    def __init__(self, period: int = 365) -> None:
        self._period = period
        self._model = 'Additive'
        
    def process_col(self, column_data: pd.Series = None) -> pd.Series:
        self.data = column_data 
        result = seasonal_decompose(self.data, model=self._model, period=self._period)
        trend = result.trend.fillna(0).values
        return trend

    @classmethod
    def process_df(cls,  dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        trend_data_dict = {column: cls().process_col(dataframe[column]) for column in dataframe.columns}
        trend_dataframes = pd.DataFrame(trend_data_dict, index=dataframe.index)
        return trend_dataframes
```

Program Executed in 14.343959668000025

Class using pandas and torch:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
import torch
import pandas as pd

class pdTrendExtractor:
        
    def __init__(self, period: int = 365) -> None:
        self._period = period
        self._model = 'Additive'
         # Store data as an instance variable
        
    def process_col(self, column_data: pd.Series = None) -> torch.Tensor:
        self.data = column_data 
        result = seasonal_decompose(self.data, model=self._model, period=self._period)
        trend = result.trend.fillna(0).values
        return torch.tensor(trend, dtype=torch.float32).view(-1, 1)

    @classmethod
    def process_df(cls,  dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> torch.Tensor:
        trend_dataframes = torch.Tensor()
        for column in dataframe.columns:
            trend_data = cls().process_col(dataframe[column])
            trend_dataframes = torch.cat((trend_dataframes, trend_data), dim=1)
        return trend_dataframes


start = timeit.default_timer()
trend_tensor = pdTrendExtractor.process_df(df_p)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
execution_time = stop - start

print("Program Executed in "+str(execution_time))
```

Program Executed in 23.14214362200073

with dict, multiprocessing & list comprehension:
As suggested by @roganjosh & @jqurious below.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class pdMTrendExtractor:
        
    def __init__(self, period: int = 365) -> None:
        self._period = period
        self._model = 'Additive'
        
    def process_col(self, column_data: pd.Series = None) -> pd.Series:
        result = seasonal_decompose(column_data, model=self._model, period=self._period)
        trend = result.trend.fillna(0).values
        return trend

    @classmethod
    def process_df(cls, dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        with Pool() as pool:
            trend_data_dict = dict(zip(dataframe.columns, pool.map(cls().process_col, [dataframe[column] for column in dataframe.columns])))

        return pd.DataFrame(trend_data_dict, index=dataframe.index)
```

Program Executed in 4.582350738997775, Nice and fast.

**Polars**

Polars & torch:

```
class plTorTrendExtractor:
        
    def __init__(self, period: int = 365) -> None:
        self._period = period
        self._model = 'Additive'
         # Store data as an instance variable
        
    def process_col(self, column_data: pl.Series = None) -> torch.Tensor:
        self.data = column_data 
        result = seasonal_decompose(self.data, model=self._model, period=self._period)
        trend = result.trend[np.isnan(result.trend)] = 0
        return torch.tensor(trend, dtype=torch.float32).view(-1, 1)

    @classmethod
    def process_df(cls,  dataframe: pl.DataFrame) -> torch.Tensor:
        trend_dataframes = torch.Tensor()
        for column in dataframe.columns:
            trend_data = cls().process_col(dataframe[column])
            trend_dataframes = torch.cat((trend_dataframes, trend_data), dim=1)
        return trend_dataframes
```

Program Executed in 13.813817326999924

polars & lamdba:

```
start = timeit.default_timer()

df_p = df_p.select([
    pl.all().map_batches(lambda x: pl.Series(seasonal_decompose(x, model="Additive", period=365).trend)).fill_nan(0)
]
)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
execution_time = stop - start

print("Program Executed in "+str(execution_time))
```

Program Executed in 82.5596211330012

I suspect this is written poorly & the reason it is so slow. I have yet find a better method.

So far I have tried, apply_many, apply, map, map_batches or map_elements.. with_columns vs select and a few other combinations.

polars only, for loop:

```
class plTrendExtractor:
        
    def __init__(self, period: int = 365) -> None:
        self._period = period
        self._model = 'Additive'
         # Store data as an instance variable
        
    def process_col(self, column_data: pl.Series = None) -> pl.DataFrame:
        self.data = column_data 
        result = seasonal_decompose(self.data, model=self._model, period=self._period)
        
        # Handle missing values by replacing NaN with 0
        result.trend[np.isnan(result.trend)] = 0
        return pl.DataFrame({column_data.name: result.trend})

    @classmethod
    def process_df(cls,  dataframe: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
        trend_dataframes = pl.DataFrame()
        for column in dataframe.columns:
            trend_data = cls().process_col(dataframe[column])
            trend_dataframes = trend_dataframes.hstack(trend_data)
        return trend_dataframes
```

Program Executed in 13.34212675299932

with list comprehensions:

I tried with polars and list comprehension. But having difficulty with polars syntax.

with a dict & for loop:

Program Executed in 13.743039597999996

with dict & list comprehension:

```
class plDict2TrendExtractor:
        
    def __init__(self, period: int = 365) -> None:
        self._period = period
        self._model = 'Additive'
        
    def process_col(self, column_data: pl.Series = None) ->  pl.Series:
        self.data = column_data 
        result = seasonal_decompose(self.data, model=self._model, period=self._period)
        result.trend[np.isnan(result.trend)] = 0
        return pl.Series(result.trend)

    @classmethod
    def process_df(cls,  dataframe: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
        trend_data_dict = {column: cls().process_col(dataframe[column]) for column in dataframe.columns}
        trend_dataframes = pl.DataFrame(trend_data_dict)
        return trend_dataframes
```

Program Executed in 13.008102383002552

with dict, multiprocessing & list comprehension:
As suggested by @roganjosh & @jqurious below.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class plMTrendExtractor:
        
    def __init__(self, period: int = 365) -> None:
        self._period = period
        self._model = 'Additive'
        
    def process_col(self, column_data: pl.Series = None) -> pl.Series:
        result = seasonal_decompose(column_data, model=self._model, period=self._period)
        result.trend[np.isnan(result.trend)] = 0
        return pl.Series(result.trend)

    @classmethod
    def process_df(cls, dataframe: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
        with Pool() as pool:
            trend_data_dict = dict(zip(dataframe.columns, pool.map(cls().process_col, [dataframe[column] for column in dataframe.columns])))

        return pl.DataFrame(trend_data_dict)
```

Program Executed in 4.997288776001369, Nice!.

With lazyFrame?

I can add lazy & collect to the `df_p.select()` method above but doing this does not improve the time. One of the key issues seems to be that the function that is passed to lazy operations needs to be lazy too. I was hoping that it might run each column in parallel.

**current conclusions & notes**

- I am getting a second to half a second of variation for some of the runs.
- Pandas and dict, seems to be reasonable. If you care about the index, then this can be a good option.
- Polars with dict and list comprehension are the "fastest". But not by much. Considering the variation even smaller diff.
- both options also have the benefit of not needing additional packages.
- There seems to be room for improvement in polars. In terms of better code, but not sure if this would improve time much. As the main, compute time is seasonal_decompose. Which takes ~0.012 seconds per column, if run alone.
- open to any feedback on improvements
- warning: i haven't done full output validation **yet** on the functions above.
- how the variable is returned from process_col does have minor impacts on speed. As expected, and part of what I was tuning here. For example, with polars if I returned numpy array I got slower time. If I returned a numpy array, but declare -> pl.series this seems about the same speed, with one or two trials being faster (then above).

**after feedback/added multiprocessing**

- surprise surprise, multiprocessing for the win. This seems to be regardless of pandas or polars.

Comment: How can you have a lazy method when it needs to consume the whole column data at once to be able to work?

Comment: If you want to parallelize it, you will probably need `multiprocessing`. This has nothing (that I can see) to do with `pandas` or `polars`, you're pulling data out of that df format, column by column, and just passing it to a set method in a serial fashion

Comment: that is my understanding, on the lazy issue. I do think there must be a faster way to iterate over the columns with `polars` without needing a `dict` to increase the speed.

Comment: I really get the impression that you don't fully understand what "lazy" means in terms of efficiency. Why do you think that _lazy_, specifically, has anything to do with this?

Comment: In any case, I gave you the suggestion on how to speed this up (regardless of the df library you use). Parallelize with `multiprocessing`; each column is processed independently, so divvy the work up between processes

Comment: The lazy concept is certainly, something i am learning. My current interpretation is similar to how sql server optimise code. with some parallel aspects too.  I was not sure how lazy would handle a non lazy function step.  It could stop to the step then move on, or it could see that there are multiple calls to this function and handle that differently. 

In this case I am simply exploring to see if it added value / improved time and taking the opportunity to learn how it works.

Comment: Nothing in python is inherently parallel. Period. The Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) means that only one bit of bytecode is being executed at any one time, in a single process. `polars` can get around this by passing off processes to compiled Rust code that is designed to work in a multi-threaded way before handing the result back to python. This is _different_ to lazy evaluation BUT that's not what you're doing here. You're taking a fully-formed column and passing it off to a single process that needs the _whole_ column in one go. In a serial way.

Comment: I'm in a catch 22 to try clear this up for you right now. It's getting late but I can see your misunderstanding and just can't test right now. I'll try demo shortly. In the meantime I've hopefully dropped some leads to look up, and I strongly suggest you get a grasp of "lazy evaluation" in general as it's a red-herring to your understanding :)

Comment: You can try to port/rewrite[seasonal_decompose](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py) into polars expressions or perhaps into a ufunc with [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html) which can be run as an expression. Alternatively, and even better, into a [polars extension](https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars) in rust. [Here's](https://pypi.org/project/polars-ds/) an example of one such extension that may or may not have a function which helps to recreate a seasonal decomp. I haven't looked through it so don't count on it.

Comment: [here's](https://github.com/ankane/stl-rust) a rust crate that does it so should just need a wrapper basically

Comment: thanks @DeanMacGregor, yeah that definitely would be a cool option.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor, I definitly think I will be looking at doing that for the large model.

Comment: I think the question could/should be simplified by getting rid of the class definitions and just compare at a high level `for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=seasonal_decompose(df[col], model="Additive", period=365).trend` to `df_p = df_p.select(
    pl.all().map_batches(lambda x: pl.Series(seasonal_decompose(x, model="Additive", period=365).trend))
)`

Comment: I've just been made aware of [this](https://docs.functime.ai/ref/seasonality/) library which seems like it would solve the problem so you don't have to reinvent the compiled seasonality wheel.

Comment: Thanks @DeanMacGregor, had a quick look at the package. I was aware of the this package, but yet to use it. From what I can tell I am doing a different type of frequency analysis. The `add_fourier_terms` is similar (likely the same), but from what I can tell i'm after a different output.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor That rust crate appears to be also part of https://pypi.org/project/augurs/ (although that seems to be the same as `.seasonal.STL`?) I found [this article](https://archive.is/SXG14/share) which says this can be done by a centered `.rolling_mean()` - I'm not a math/stats person but perhaps someone else can confirm if these can be used?

Comment: @jqurious, the answer is always be... it depends on what you are after/purpose.

Comment: Perhaps I should have worded it as *"Are either of these approaches equivalent?"* - Out of interest https://github.com/sd2k/stl-rust/pull/1 says it's `~20x` faster than `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL`

Comment: thanks @jqurious that does look interesting, definitely for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to Polars, using `.select()` and `.map_batches()` in this type of situation is kind of an *"anti-pattern"*.

You are putting all of the data through Polars expression engine, to pass it back out to Python to run your external function, to pass it back into Polars again.

You can bypass that and simply pass each `Series` directly to `seasonal_decompose()` (similar to how you loop through each column in the Pandas approach):

```py
pl.DataFrame({
    col.name: seasonal_decompose(col, model="Additive", period=365).trend
    for col in df_p
})
```

One thing I did notice though is that if you create a LazyFrame from each column and use [`pl.collect_all()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.collect_all.html#polars-collect-all) it speeds up the `.map_batches()` approach by ~50%. (Perhaps this could be investigated.)

(Although still slightly slower than the comprehension.)

```py
lf = df_p.lazy()

lazy_columns = [ 
    lf.select(pl.col(col).map_batches(
        lambda x: pl.Series(seasonal_decompose(x, model="Additive", period=365).trend))
    ) 
    for col in lf.columns 
]

out = pl.concat(pl.collect_all(lazy_columns), how="horizontal")
```

Essentially the question becomes *"How can I parallelize a Python for loop?"*

Which as @roganjosh pointed out is done with [multiprocessing.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/misc/multiprocessing/)

```py
from multiprocessing import get_context

...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    df_p = ...

    with get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
        columns = pool.map(process_column, (col for col in df_p))
```

Out of interest, the example runs ~50% faster for me with multiprocessing versus the regular comprehension.

But it's very task/data/platform-specific so you would have benchmark it locally.

Comment: That's really interesting that constructing a new df from the dict comprehension is just as fast as the pandas method but I don't understand why the select method is orders of magnitude worse. I would think any overhead the select is handling, the creation of the df handles too.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I think the df creation is essentially "free" here. As for `.select()`, it takes `37s` - the "manual" `.collect_all()` version takes `20s` and the regular comprehension `17s`. So `17` vs `20` is reasonable overhead but I'm not sure why the original version is slower.

Comment: for comparison to the other times above, your lazy method came in at "Program Executed in 43.89767186300014".  So nice improvement over my polars only version.

Comment: Thanks @AaronC - that matches my results, basically it halved the run-time. Maybe it could be filed as a *"Performance Issue"* because Polars could just do this automatically for you if it was always a faster approach. But I'm not sure if it's just specific to this particular task (or what exactly Polars ends up doing differently internally). I don't have the knowledge to debug it further.

Comment: Just to follow up on my previous comment, testing the `pl.collect_all()` approach in other benchmarks, it ends up being slower. So it appears that whether or not it could be faster is completely task-specific.

Comment: Hi  jqurious. i would like to give @roganjosh the credit, as they was first and it seems like they have something important to add.  However, if they don't post a response, i'll tick yours. shame comments can't be given the credit.

Comment: @AaronC I appreciate the update. The main reason I posted this was just to address the point about not using `.select()` + `.map_batches()`. This use-case needs everything "in memory", in which case you can just deal with `pl.Series` objects directly. It was too large for a comment, so I had to post an "Answer" (It's probably a "half-answer", so I wasn't expecting it to be accepted.)